# Go Postgres prepared statements issue using up all connections

Tags: postgresql, go, prepared-statement

My plan was to create all the prepared statements at startup and store them in a map. Then when I need one I'll go an take it from the map and for example make an UPDATE. However after using the prepared statement successfully it won't close (I can see it in pgAdmin being idle). Now my problem is when I call this UPDATE prepared statement often enough it starts using all connections until max_connections defined by postgres and keeps them open.

I could close them after usage. But then I would have to recreate the prepared statement when I want to call UPDATE again. This sounds like unneccessary overhead. Is there another solution? This only seems to happen with the UPDATE statement and not with INSERT. I'm using the Go "database/sql" library.

Here an example code:

```
type ItemPreparedStmtID int

const (
     CreateItem ItemPreparedStmtID = iota
     UpdateStatus
)

// Creates an map with enums as key and prepared statements as value. Returns a map. 
func (ipg *ItemPG) createEnumMap() map[ItemPreparedStmtID]string {
    return map[ItemPreparedStmtID]string{
        CreateItem: fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO %s.item (collectionid, signature, urn, creation_date, public, public_actions) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING itemid", ipg.schema),
        UpdateStatus: fmt.Sprintf("UPDATE %s.item SET status=$1 WHERE itemid=$2", ipg.schema),
    }
}

// Creates all the prepared statements and adds them to a map. Returning any error encountered.
func (ipg *ItemPG) CreatePreparedStatements() error {
    enumMap := ipg.createEnumMap()
    var err error
    for k, v := range enumMap {
        ipg.preparedStatements[k], err = ipg.CreatePreparedStatement(v)
        if err != nil {
            return errors.Wrapf(err, "cannot create sql query %s", v)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

// Creates and returns a prepared statement according to the passed sql string.
// Returning sql prepared statement and any error encountered.
func (ipg *ItemPG) CreatePreparedStatement(sqlstr string) (*sql.Stmt, error) {
    stmt, err := ipg.db.Prepare(sqlstr)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrapf(err, "cannot execute sql %s", sqlstr)
    }
    return stmt, nil
}
func (ipg *ItemPG) UpdateStatus(itemid int64, status string) error {
    params := []interface{}{
        status,
        itemid,
    }
    if err := ipg.preparedStatements[UpdateStatus].QueryRow(params...).Err(); err != nil {
        return errors.Wrapf(err, "cannot update item status item: %d - status: %s", itemid, status)
    }
    // ipg.preparedStatements[UpdateStatus].Close()
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Don't use `QueryRow` if you're not querying a row. Use `Exec` for SQL commands from which you do not desire to scan any data. Use `QueryRow` ONLY if you intend to call the `Scan` method on the returned row.

Comment: When invoking QueryRow you get back an *sql.Row value, this value needs to be closed after you're done with it, if you discard it you can't close it, if you don't close it you'll leak connections. *sql.Row is closed by invoking the Scan method.

Comment: Rather than storing prepared statements for the lifetime of the application, which consumes memory and network connections, maybe consider using stored procedures.